# How can i auto increment and shorten a string as textfield?

Tags: python, django

im currently trying to do a project management app and i need to autoincrement project count and add  shortened string from department. For example if Product Development add a project to site i need to show in table like this PD_1

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass a function to a field `default` and use it to generate an incremental text value:

```py
def create_project_reference():
   projects = Project.objects.filter(# some filter)
   return f'PD_{projects.count()+1}'

class Project(models.Model):
   project_reference = models.CharField(..., 
      default=create_project_reference, 
      editable=False
   )
```

The problem with this is that the default callable doesn't get `self` from the model that has been created, so you can't create dynamic filters. An alternative is to override the `save()` function of your model and you can then access `self`, pass it into your function, and use its info to set your filters:

```py
def create_project_reference(project):
   projects = Project.objects.filter(department=project.department)
   return f'PD_{projects.count()+1}'

class Project(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project_reference = create_project_reference(self)
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

There are limitations of overriding the `save()` function as it doesn't work with the bulk `update()` function - but that should be fine for a value that is set once when the object is created.